# Off-grid computing

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current, solar-energy

I am designing the electrical system for a school bus to tiny home conversion (skoolie, by jargon.) The current iteration is entirely solar powered, somewhere around 2640 W in panels, and likely 1000 Ah or more in batteries.

Currently adding up my expected loads, I would like to still have access to my gaming PC, a NAS, several PoE IP cameras, PoE capable network switch, my remote networking equipment (including a cell booster and sat internet) and a rack-mount server to run TensorFlow object detection on the feeds from the cameras, as well as whatever other containerized applications I want to mess about with that week.

This is in addition to all the usual loads a small house needs:

- fridge (24 VDC)
- induction cooktop (240 VAC)
- oven (120/240 VAC)
- mini-split AC unit (48 VDC)
- combo washer/dryer
- electric on-demand water heater (120/240 VAC)
- pumps
- lighting
- a fan or two (12 V or less)

My question has to do with the computing equipment specifically. It seems asinine and inefficient to me to generate all this perfectly good DC power, run an AC inverter, send that power to an ATX/server/whatever PSU converter to be spun back down to DC 12 V/5 V/3.3 V to all the internal loads.

Would you recommend the legwork/internet scouring to find the DC to DC power supplies for all these units, or are the perceived "inefficiencies" of DC->AC->DC conversion really not a big deal?

Please keep in mind that I am both very new to the EE board on StackExchange, and very new to electrical engineering in general. I just learned the basic conversions between watts, volts and amperes last week. I am looking for a dummy check here, essentially.

Comment: atx power supplies are 90%+ efficient. inverters can be 90%+ too. that leaves small margins for optimizing. You're probably only going to be able save 10, 15, maybe 20% max. . Certainly anything that takes DC in can be cut out of the AC loop with a cheapish DC-DC buck/boost converter, which can be 97% efficient in the latest (eg. synchronous, Gan) models. The PoE stuff is likely not anywhere near that efficient, but it also tends not to draw large currents. it's probably cheaper just to add 10% more solar capacity.

Comment: Datacenters did (still do?) this for a while (google I think it was).  They ran large 12V buses directly to the motherboards.  Looks like they are still doing it, but upped the voltage to 48V. https://www.edn.com/data-center-next-generation-power-supply-solutions-for-improved-efficiency/

Answer (score 1):

Say you got 2640W peak solar panels... On overcast days, the power you'll get versus all your electrical loads seems... wildly optimistic. For example, over the last few months (jan-may) my 3kW peak installation in the south of France produces between 1.5kWh and 20kWh per day depending on weather. So, an overcast day produces barely enough to take a shower. Sorry to rain on your parade XD

I think you need to find a solar energy prediction website and check what you're going to get according to where you plan to put the bus. Note that many parking spots are in the vicinity of trees and buildings, which cast shadows, and solar panels don't produce much in shadow. They like full sunlight. Obviously, if the panels lie flat on the roof, they will work very well in summer, but only barely in winter, and not at all if there's snow.

> electric on-demand water - heater (120/240VAC)

An on-demand water heater will blow your inverter budget. Once the batteries are charged, the solar panels aren't doing anything useful. So, replace with tank water heater, 50l, run it with excess power from solar panels. This won't solve the overcast day problem. So, perhaps gas, or waste heat from the engine, or a small thermal solar panel, etc. Basically, storing hot water instead of energy is much cheaper than batteries.

50 liters of 70°C water stores about 2 kWh before the temperature drops to 35°C and the shower becomes noticeably less warm. That's the equivalent of 12V 166Ah.

> Fridge (24VDC)
> mini-split AC unit (48VDC)

You've already got 3 DC voltages: 24, 48, and most likely 12. Well, DC-DCs aren't expensive, so why not.

> induction cooktop (240VAC)
> oven (120/240VAC)
> combo washer/dryer

All of this will dramatically increase your inverter budget due to the huge power demands. If there are several overcast days in a row, you will probably have to purchase a gas powered stove, which would be the best option anyway if you're off-grid. Electricity stored in batteries is expensive, and heat needs a whole lot of it. Butane/propane stores a lot more heat per volume.

> pumps
> lighting
> a fan or two (12V or less)

No problem.

> Currently adding up my expected loads, I would like to still have access to my gaming PC, a NAS, several PoE IP cameras, PoE capable network switch, my remote networking equipment (including a cell booster and sat internet) and a rack-mount server to run TensorFlow object detection on the feeds from the cameras, as well as whatever other containerized applications

There's something missing in your question: measurements of how much power all that stuff uses. That's the first thing you should do, get a wattmeter and make a spreadsheet. For example if you want to run a server off-grid, it should be efficient, which means ARM, not x86. Remember on an overcast day, you have about 1-1.5 kWh to spend, which is an average power of 62.5W. If there's a lot of sun, you'll have more of course.

So, you have a lot of measurements to do, and hunting for equipment that doesn't use much energy. If you want off-grid with only 2.6kWpeak of solar, the gaming PC will be for the sunny days, but for the rest of the time, you'll need a laptop.

Note [MiniBox](https://www.mini-box.com/M4-ATX-HV?sc=8&category=981) has a whole range of PicoPsu's, basically it's a bunch of DC-DC converters with an ATX power connector to stick on your motherboard. So you can power an ATX PC with DC using that.

My off-grid-backup 3kWp installation is designed to run the fridge and freezer only. On a sunny day, it'll soften my electricity bill a lot more of course, but I sized the panels and batteries to get enough power to run just the fridge, freezer, and a few lights in case of blackout and bad weather. And I got a gas camping stove. Of course, I'm not off-grid, but I'm counting on blackouts courtesy of the Germans unplugging their nuke powerplants.

Basically, you can't power a modern lifestyle (and especially a dryer...) with this sort of solar installation.

If you have access to on-grid electricity, then it's a no-brainer. Simply compute the cost of a kWh from batteries, including the cycle life of the batteries. It will most likely be quite expensive.

Comment: Yeah, I never really expected the dryer to run on battery, but its nice to have when Ive got shore power. Thanks for your detailed run-down though!